# Share ActionBar between different activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an application with an `FragmentActivity` called `MainActivity` which holds two fragments, one menu fragment to the left and one content fragment to the right. On a large device both of these fragments are shown. On a small device only the menu fragment is shown and when the user presses an item in said menu the content fragment is displayed in a new `Activity`.

Lets say the user is currently using the application on his phone and only the menu is visible:

The `ActionBar` of `MainActivity` can be manipulated by user choices in the menu. When the user selects a specific menu item, a new `Activity` launches to display the content fragment. When this `Activity` pops up the `ActionBar` of this new `Activity` is a new `ActionBar` and therefore does not resemble the `ActionBar` of `FragmentActivity` (`MainActivity`).

I figured I could pass the `ActionBar` from `MainActivity` to the `Activity` which displays the content fragment through `Intent` extras, or making the `ActionBar` static and reference it like `MainActivity.actionBar` or similar, but I ran into problems very quickly :)

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Basically, what I want is to share a single `ActionBar` reference between all my activities.

Comment: Just out of plain curiousity, could you provide an image showing your `ActionBar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's better to use fragments instead of activities. I mean show `menu fragment`, and when you need to show `content fragment` just put `content fragment` into the place (container) where was `menu fragment`. I think better/easier to organize fragment replace/change logics than trying to share actionbar between different activities.

Comment: You're probably right. I got my mind set on my approach from a tutorial I did but I agree your suggestion sounds better. Thanks :)