# Android 4.2 : Main Activity actionbar hides launching the new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am developing an android application, where in MainActivity i am creating the actionbar with tabs for the application. i do have set listener for Tab click of actionbar which launches new activity in the application...till this everything is working fine.
Problem is : When new activity get created on Tab click, ActionBar of the application (which is created in main activity) is not shown....it shows application icon and name but NO TABS which i created in Main Activity.

I am no using any supported libraries to support previous versions of android. I am using Android 4.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to extend the onCreateOptionMenu method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779340/see-action-bar-across-all-activities-android).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294021/share-actionbar-between-different-activities) provides somewhat guidance on a possible solution, using fragments instead of activities.

Comment: Thanks i will look these links and get back

Answer (score 0):

I think the first answer to this question might help you:
[Android - Switch Tabs from within an Activity within a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541802/android-switch-tabs-from-within-an-activity-within-a-tab)

Particularly the links to the example source code